# Whats the meaning of this error in Kafka broker logs?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What does this error mean?

> Could not append error in kafka broker for streams application
>   partitions?

[image]

I am seeing too many of these errors whenever I start my kafka streams application. 
What does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: the link is dead; please update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Kafka. It is related to 
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7190 and 
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6817.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/646ec948794c927e4ffa5f96d60b5b9f7fe8f228/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/ReplicaManager.scala#L782

Comment: The topic here KStream-KEY-SELECT is created by Kafka stream application itself and it has a retention period of 9223372036854775807 milliseconds which I believe is infinite. 

And yes, I am using Exactly Once semantics for my stream application which I need for my Kafka stream application. I'll see if I can remove that but then I'll need to check if it doesn't break the logic. 

Anyhow, given the retention is set to infinite, what can be the reason behind this error?

Comment: another possible reason is  that your kafka broker did not have unclean leader election disabled, and there was some data loss in the cluster that has caused inconsistency among brokers.  If that is the case, you can delete the topics and re-run the application to see if that helps.

Comment: Highly unlikely because none of my brokers got down.
And yes, thanks for the suggestion I was able to fix the problem by changing processing guarantee to atleast once.   
But I still don't know the reason behind the error.

Comment: 6817 is related but not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug that is going to be addressed via https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-360%3A+Improve+handling+of+unknown+producer

You can't do much about it, but need to wait for the fix.

The problem is, that Kafka Streams actively deletes data (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150) from repartition topics and thus increasing retention time does not help -- in fact, Kafka Streams configures repartition topic with `retention.ms=MAX_VALUE` already.

The only thing you could do, is to increase topic configs `segment.bytes` and `segment.ms` config for the repartition topic. Making segments larger reduces the chance that transactional producer state is lost, because the active segment is not subject for active data purging, and thus data is kept for a longer time.

Comment: Hi Matt, Can you please comment on my other question as well. I am really struggling with random Broker disconnections  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684595/disconnectexception-breaks-the-entire-kafka-cluster